# Timezone for my country doesn't give correct answer

Tags: php, date, timezone

I am trying to echo date, simple code, but result is not correct for my country.
Result is  `04.10.2014` and it should be `03.10.2014`

Here is my code
**PHP**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Sarajevo");
$my_date = date("d.m.Y");
echo $my_date;

?>
```

Comment: adjust time on server. may be it is wrong.

Comment: It works fine for me. As @mithunsatheesh says, the problem seems to be that your server's time is wrong.

Comment: I am using "localhost", could u explain me how to change server time? :)

Comment: You should run NTP on your machine to keep its clock correct.

Comment: What server/os are you using. Are you running xampp?

Comment: Yeah, i am using xampp

Comment: It works as expected at my side. Check your server time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to C:\xampp\php\php.ini or your path, open it.

Find:

```
 date.timezone = "<something>"
```

Change it to `date.timezone = "Europe/Sarajevo"`

Restart your XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server's timezone is set correctly because PHP always uses the default sever time as a reference.

Check if correct by:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get . ' ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

You'll know if your server's time zone is messed up if the above code returns something unexpected.

If it is messed up, you'll just have to adjust your timezone offset manually.

If you need to change your timezone, just change this via system settings on Windows/Mac. If you're on Linux try these:

```
Ubuntu: dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
Redhat: redhat-config-date
CentOS/Fedora: system-config-date
FreeBSD/Slackware: tzselect
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is result i got "2014-10-04 04:32:23" it should be "2014-10-03 19:32:23

Comment: Yes, that means you need to change your system time. What's your operating system?

Comment: My System is WIndows 7

Comment: Follow steps indicated here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows/set-clock#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Then adjust your timezone to your correct location.